# Select statement getting blocked on LGWR session

Tags: oracle, blocking

During the peak windows of my application when it tries to save large amount of data, i have noticed that even `Select` queries are waiting on  LGWR operation.
In the table `dba_hist_active_sess_history`, I can see select query waiting with blocked session column showing LGWR process.
This leads to a situation where database runs out of connections.
I don't want Select operations to wait for LGWR operation as its querying historical data which is a different row.
Any ideas how this can be achieved.

Comment: It might happen. Oracle is sometimes lazy and leaves dirty blocks in buffer cache. When SELECT sees them it tries to write them onto disk. This process is called "oracle delayed block cleanout". I'm afraid there is no simple solution for such a situation. Check your AWS and look at response time of your disks.

Comment: There *may* be a simple solution, but this likely is a question for a database administer. You might have to resize your log files to reduce log switches, or maybe have fewer copies of logs, or fix an IO problem in a storage device. I've never seen delayed block cleanout consistently cause problems, so you might have a serious problem for an administrator. (Assuming that you are counting the number of waits and only dealing with the top waits. There are always a few bizarre waits floating around.) You might want to try moving this question to the DBA site.